# Combine odd and even indexes of two array columns in matlab / octave

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave

I have an array **(b)** with two columns I would like to combine the data with even indexes of the second column with the data of the odd indexes of the first.
**PS:  the numbers won't be this linear so I can't use linspace command it's just an example.**

```
a1=[1;2;3;4;5]
a2=[1.5;2.5;3.5;4.5;5.5]
b=[a1,a2]

b array:
1.0000   1.5000
2.0000   2.5000
3.0000   3.5000
4.0000   4.5000
5.0000   5.5000

Final output below I'm trying to get:
1
2.5
3
4.5
5
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, the final output contains sorted numbers?

Comment: @tashuhka The example does look sorted but I put in bold "the numbers won't be this linear so I can't use linspace command" I tried to make the example as simple as possible, maybe I made it to simple. Next time I will use random numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
[nb_rows,nb_cols] = size(b);
c = zeros(nb_rows,1);
c(1:2:end) = b(1:2:end,1);
c(2:2:end) = b(2:2:end,2);
```

Answer (score 2):

This handles the cases that the number of elements in `a1` (and `a2`)  is odd or even:

```
c = b.'; %'//
n = numel(a1);
ind = bsxfun(@plus, [1;4], 0:4:2*n-1);
result = c(ind(1:n)).';
```

Answer (score -2):

You can combine both vectors (odd and even), then sort them:

```
c = sort([a1(1:2:end); a2(2:2:end)])
```

Comment: `a1` and `a2` are not necessarily sorted, so this will change element order in the result

Comment: Where did the OP said explicitly that the vectors are not sorted? I actually think that they are sorted because OP commented that wanted to use `linspace()`, which creates an ordered vector, but didn't because the numbers are not linearly spaced. Anyway, my assumptions could be wrong or not. But in case of uncertainty, it must be the OP who clarifies the question.

Comment: When the asker doesn't say the inputs satisfy a certain restriction (being sorted), it's wise to assume they don't necessarily satisfy it. For example, assuming the values are all multiples of `0.5` would not be warranted either